# Gulp - variable not visible for gulp.src

Tags: variables, gulp, frontend

I have 2 tasks in gulp.
In the first one, I am initializing a variable with the path of a file. In the second task I´m trying to read the variable. If I use console.log it´s works, it is showing me the value on the screen. 
The problem is when I´m trying to put it like a source path: gulp.src([variable]). It doen´t work anymore. What is it wrong?

Thanks

```
gulp.task('tarea', function() {
    return gulp.src(['prueba/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(prompt.prompt([{
    .....
    }], function(){
        variable = 'prueba.html';
    }))
});
gulp.task('tareaMain', ['tarea'], function() {
    console.log(variable);
    //variable= 'prueba.html';
    gulp.src([variable])
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this site requires that you post your questions in *English* only. Please translate this yourself; someone else translating for you will not help you understand comments and answers, or respond to feedback.

Comment: There is also a [Spanish sister site](https://es.stackoverflow.com) if you want to use your native language.

Comment: Are you using gulp4?